# Having a for loop with two parameter

Tags: for-loop

I am trying to have this loop but it says its not possible. How can I create these kinds of loops?

```
for i in range (sposA,sposB) and for j in range(eposB+1,sposB,-1): 
    if tempstr[i] == ctempstr[j]: 
        pcount += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In basically any language, such a construct would be ambiguous.  Are you trying to loop in two dimensions (if each index list is `x` and `y` long, are you doing `x`*`y` things total?) or in parallel (are the indices the same length, e.g. `x`, and paired, so you only do `x` things?).

If you want to loop in two dimensions, you simply nest loops:

```
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
       doStuff(i, j)
```

If they're parallel, you can either create some functional dependence between them so you can convert index `i` into index `j`, or combine the indicies:

```
for i in range(x):
    j = f(i)
    doStuff(i, j)
```

or

```
for i, j in zip(range(x), range(y)):
    doStuff(i, j)
```

The above stuff is in Python-pseudocode, but the control structures are broadly applicable in any imperative language (C, Python, Java...).